# Allow admin user to give permission to customer registration in Magento shop

Tags: magento, permissions, administrator

I want to set a rule to allow administrator to give permission to customers when they register an account in the Magento Shop. Currently, Customers can register an account without asking Administrator's permission.

Anyone here knows about how to do it or any extensions I can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is what you're asking for. I've used this with great success on a website where products were only available to certified professionals, so their account needed to be approved before they could login. https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation/tree/master/app/code/community/Netzarbeiter/CustomerActivation